# Python - how to automatically translate after inputing the text in the input box

Tags: python, tkinter

Hope you all in good.
I'm trying to code with python to make google do translate. It has been successfully done, but now 1 challenge is i don't want to press on the translate button, i want it automatically after inputing the text in the input field without press on the translate button ? Can you please help suggest some idea to me to do this ?

my code as belơw:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button, Frame, font
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM, END
from typing import Text
import googletrans
#print(googletrans.LANGUAGES)
root = tk.Tk()
from googletrans import Translator
# t = Translator()
# b = a.text
# print(b)
root.geometry("720x900")
root.title("google translator")

title1 = tk.Label(
    root,
    text="Google Translator",
    font=('arial',20)
)
# title2 = tk.Label(
#     root,
#     text="put what you need to translate to Vietnamese",
#     font=('Arial',15),
# )

title1.pack(pady=5)
# title2.pack(pady=5)
# box1 = Text(root, width=30,height=10, font=('arial',12))
box = tk.Text(
    root,
    width=55,
    height=15,
    font=('Roboto',14)
)
box.pack(pady=10)

def tran():
    input1 = box.get("1.0","end")
    t=Translator()
    print(input1)
    a = t.translate(input1,src='en',dest='vi')
    b = a.text
    box1.insert(END,b)
def clear():
    box.delete("1.0","end")
    box1.delete("1.0","end")
Button_frame=tk.Frame(root).pack(side=BOTTOM)
clear_button = tk.Button(
    Button_frame,
    text="clear content",
    font=('Arial',10,'bold'),
    bg = '#303030',
    fg="#FFFFFF",
    command=clear
)
trans_button = tk.Button(
    Button_frame,
    text="translate",
    font=('Arial',10,'bold'),
    bg = 'yellow',
    fg="red",
    command=tran
)
clear_button.place(x=290,y=410)
trans_button.place(x= 150,y=410)
# clear_button.pack(pady=5)
#clear_button.pack(pady=5)
box1 = tk.Text(
    root,
    width=55,
    height=15,
    font=('Roboto',14)
)
box1.pack(pady=60)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264244/10840671 - I think you can use this to bind the release of keys in that text box to trigger the translation function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think what you need here is using the `.trace_add()` method so you can trigger an event which is the translation method in your case whenever you write in the box.

You need to assign `StringVar()` to both text variables.

Next, you have to setup the `.trace_add ('w',tran)`(where the "w" means write)

Comment: Hi Dharman, may you let me know how you assign myvar = stringvar() for the whole text in the input box , I tried to test with below code, but it seems that myvar doesn't keep any value of the input text box:  def callback(var,indx,mode):
    myvar = box.get("1.0","end")
    print(myvar)
myvar.trace_add('write',callback)

Comment: box is an tk.text ,  and i also define myvar = tk.Stringvar() as global variable.

Comment: hey @thangvc91 I think this website can help you [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/)

Comment: hi Bros, I have refered trace_add feature you mentioned above , but still can not applied in my case, i have 2 textbox , 1 for the language need to be translated, and the other for translating , wondering how i can assigned them the same variable as the example in the link you gave.